# How to do exact string match in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two values in table PC and PC/name. But when I write a query,

```
select * from TransDetail TD where td.ModUserId like '%PC/%'
```

it gives me both results. Is there a way to get only one record?

Comment: Keep in mind the `%` signifies a wildcard when using `LIKE`.  So '%PC%' will match anything with PC in it.  '%PC' will match ending in PC, and 'PC%' will match beginning with PC.  'PC' will match exactly PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make your WHERE clause like this:

```
select * 
from TransDetail TD
where TD.ModUserId ='PC'
```

This way you will get the results which are matched to 'PC' **only**. 
The *like* that you made is giving your results of cases that PC can be start/middle/end of the field

Answer (score 2):

You should use this query instead for an exact match of the value PC:

```
SELECT * FROM TransDetail TD WHERE TD.ModUserId = 'PC';
```

When using % in the WHERE clause you are using a wildcard that stands for 0 or more occurrences of characters in that position.

Also, if you are actually using `LIKE '%PC/%'` it should match the value PC/name and not the value PC, because of the extra '/' character in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`select * from TransDetail TD where td.ModUserId like '%PC'`