# Find exact word match in a list of word with SQL Query

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table like the following table.

```
entityId |  mId      |  supertTypes                     |  SubTypes
------------------------------------------------------------
12       |  /m.098yu | /m.0yhtg, /m.089hj0__            | Null
13       |  /m.kju_c_| /m.0ypwec, /m.0bnm0__, /m.0hgt   | /m.098yu
```

My query is:

```
select mId from table where superTypes= /m.0yhtg;
```

The answer should be **/m.098yu**

I wrote the following queres based on [page1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220364/how-exact-match-string-in-sql)  and [page2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999180/mysql-search-exact-word-with-in-word)but I could not get correct result.

```
select mId from table where supertypes RLIKE "[[:<:]]/m.0yhtg[[:>:]]";

Select mId from table where supertypes LIKE '/m.0yhtg';
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try adding wildcards to your `LIKE` statement? `LIKE '%/m.0yhtg%'`?

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a column.  Build another table.

Comment: @Mcadam331 Yes I tried but it did not work for all kind of values.

Comment: Hmm. Also, I agree with Rick James on this, here is more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @RickJames I got this suggestion from _juergen d_. But I use this table instead of storing my information in a file. Therefore, use multi table is a kind of cheating ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set` for that but that requires a list without whitespaces. So you need to remove them first with `replace`

```
Select mId from table 
where find_in_set('/m.0yhtg', replace(supertypes, ' ', '')) > 0
```

But you should actually rather change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column!

A better DB design would be adding a new table

```
entities table
--------------
entityId
mId


types table
----------------
id
name


entity_types table
------------------
entity_id
type_id
is_super_type
```

Instead of the field `is_super_type` you could add another table called `entity_subTypes` and name the `entity_types` table `entity_supertypes` instead.

Comment: each entity can have more than one super type and I am not sure about the number of super type. How can I index them in more than one column?